# Can you "escalate down" on an escalator?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In a recent article in *New York* magazine, a reporter described an entourage of politicians preparing to leave a building

> " . . . we headed for the exits, and as we were all *escalating down* to the lobby . . ."

A survey of definitions for the verb *escalate* on onelook.com all reveal meanings [such as](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/escalate)

> to make or become greater or more serious

[Cambridge](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/escalate) and several other dictionaries note that the verb is derived from the noun *escalator*, (which began as a coined trademark word that has now become the generic term for moving staircase).

A few dictionaries, such as [this one](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/escalate?r=66) suggest that the original meaning of *escalate* was just that -- to ride an escalator, and list a definition

> to raise, lower, rise, or descend on or as if on an escalator.

All of these *ride-the-escalator* definitions seem to be based on one listing in Random House Dictionary.

Is an acceptance of the original meaning re-emerging?  And if so, can one *escalate down*, which ironically seems to fly in the face of the more common usage of escalate (up)?

Comment: Can't you accept that this was a self-consciously clever bit of writing?

Comment: @Robusto I could, but I want to be sure that I am not missing an emerging re-neologism (paleologism?).

Comment: You "downsculate" and a "downsculator". Seen in John Varley's work. Paired with "upsculator", of course.

Comment: I think this is Not A Real Question. Who ever says they *escalate **up*** an escalator? (even in constructions where they don't actually use the word *escalator*)

Comment: When I want to go up I take the escalator.  When I want to go down I take deescalator.

Answer (score 7):

Well, of course you can't, but of course he just did.

Much as chickens cannot cross a road without having their motives questioned, this is amusing because we can clearly see how he is back-forming *escalator* into *escalate* meaning "what one does on an escalator" when it's contrary to the word's normal meaning.

We shouldn't repeat the use, not so much because it is technically wrong, as because it was funnier the first time.

Comment: Normally _escalate_ is used only in a metaphorical sense, where it means "go up" and not "go down". If used in a literal sense, it's a self-consciously clever bit of writing, as Robusto said. Nothing neotenic to see here; move along.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper term would be "de-escalate". — i.e., after the crisis de-escalated, we de-escalated to the lobby and enjoyed a frozen chocolate coffee deliquisence.

Comment: Hello, Ernst, and welcome to the ELU. Please take a [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how to answer more thoroughly on this site. You may want to come back after and edit your answer by providing some reference. Good luck.